# Conditional if in asynchronous python program with twisted

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I'm creating a program that uses the Twisted module and callbacks.
However, I keep having problems because the asynchronous part goes wrecked.

I have learned (also from previous questions..) that the callbacks will be executed at a certain point, but this is unpredictable.

However, I have a certain program that goes like

```
j = calc(a)
i = calc2(b)
f = calc3(c)

if s:
  combine(i, j, f)
```

Now the boolean `s` is set by a callback done by `calc3`. Obviously, this leads to an undefined error because the callback is not executed before the `s` is needed.
However, I'm unsure how you `SHOULD` do if statements with asynchronous programming using Twisted. I've been trying many different things, but can't find anything that works.

Is there some way to use conditionals that require callback values?

Also, I'm using `VIFF` for secure computations (which uses Twisted): [VIFF](http://viff.dk)

Comment: Are `calc`, `calc2`, `calc3` magical VIFF things?  Or are they normal functions that each return a Deferred?  If they are magical VIFF things, can you expand your question to include their definitions?

Comment: All functions are "normal" functions, no `VIFF` stuff. Except that `calc3` involves shares (type of deffered) and the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is `twisted.internet.defer.gatherResults`:

```
d = gatherResults([calc(a), calc2(b), calc3(c)])
def calculated((j, i, f)):
    if s:
        return combine(i, j, f)
d.addCallback(calculated)
```

However, this still has the problem that `s` is undefined.  I can't quite tell how you expect `s` to be defined.  If it is a local variable in `calc3`, then you need to return it so the caller can use it.

Perhaps calc3 looks something like this:

```
def calc3(argument):
    s = bool(argument % 2)
    return argument + 1
```

So, instead, consider making it look like this:

```
Calc3Result = namedtuple("Calc3Result", "condition value")

def calc3(argument):
    s = bool(argument % 2)
    return Calc3Result(s, argument + 1)
```

Now you can rewrite the calling code so it actually works:

It's sort of unclear what you're asking here.  It sounds like you know what callbacks are, but if so then you should be able to arrive at this answer yourself:

```
d = gatherResults([calc(a), calc2(b), calc3(c)])
def calculated((j, i, calc3result)):
    if calc3result.condition:
        return combine(i, j, calc3result.value)
d.addCallback(calculated)
```

Or, based on your comment below, maybe `calc3` looks more like this (this is the last guess I'm going to make, if it's wrong and you'd like more input, then please actually *share* the definition of `calc3`):

```
def _calc3Result(result, argument):
    if result == "250":
        # SMTP Success response, yay
        return Calc3Result(True, argument)
    # Anything else is bad
    return Calc3Result(False, argument)

def calc3(argument):
    d = emailObserver("The argument was %s" % (argument,))
    d.addCallback(_calc3Result)
    return d
```

Fortunately, this definition of `calc3` will work just fine with the `gatherResults` / `calculated` code block immediately above.

Comment: I am upvoting this. And I had never came across gatherResults earlier. So something new for me as well

Comment: The boolean `s` is defined by the deferred on which the callback is done by `calc3`. So the value of the deferred needs to be known before the boolean can be set, which is the problem.

Comment: Using some ideas from this answer, I've managed to solve the problem with the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `if` in the callback.  You may use `Deferred` to structure your callback.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous answer - the preocessing logic should be handled in callback chain, below is simple code demonstration how this could work. `C{DelayedTask}` is a dummy implementation of a task which happens in the future and fires supplied deferred.

So we first construct a special object - `C{ConditionalTask}` which takes care of storring the multiple results and servicing callbacks.

calc1, calc2 and calc3 returns the deferreds, which have their callbacks pointed to `C{ConditionalTask}.x_callback`.

Every `C{ConditionalTask}.x_callback` does a call to `C{ConditionalTask}.process` which checks if all of the results have been registered and fires on a full set.

Additionally - `C{ConditionalTask}.c_callback` sets a flag of wheather or not the data should be processed at all.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

class DelayedTask(object):
    """
    Delayed async task dummy implementation
    """
    def __init__(self,delay,deferred,retVal):
        self.deferred = deferred
        self.retVal = retVal
        reactor.callLater(delay, self.on_completed)
    def on_completed(self):
        self.deferred.callback(self.retVal)


class ConditionalTask(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.resultA=None
        self.resultB=None
        self.resultC=None
        self.should_process=False

    def a_callback(self,result):
        self.resultA = result
        self.process()

    def b_callback(self,result):
        self.resultB=result
        self.process()

    def c_callback(self,result):
        self.resultC=result
        """
        Here is an abstraction for your "s" boolean flag, obviously the logic
        normally would go further than just setting the flag, you could
        inspect the result variable and do other strange stuff
        """
        self.should_process = True 
        self.process()

    def process(self):
        if None not in (self.resultA,self.resultB,self.resultC):
            if self.should_process:
                print 'We will now call the processor function and stop reactor'
                reactor.stop()



def calc(a):
    deferred = defer.Deferred()
    DelayedTask(5,deferred,a)
    return deferred

def calc2(a):
    deferred = defer.Deferred()
    DelayedTask(5,deferred,a*2)
    return deferred

def calc3(a):
    deferred = defer.Deferred()
    DelayedTask(5,deferred,a*3)
    return deferred

def main():
    conditional_task = ConditionalTask()
    dFA = calc(1)
    dFB = calc2(2)
    dFC = calc3(3)

    dFA.addCallback(conditional_task.a_callback)
    dFB.addCallback(conditional_task.b_callback)
    dFC.addCallback(conditional_task.c_callback)

    reactor.run()
```

Comment: No it is not idiomatic twisted code. It serves entirely different purpose - allows to explain overly simplified idea of async. result and joining multiple async results. I didn't start rolling him towards DeferredList and chained deferreds / stacked to oversimplify the solution. You and @glyph are both allowed to pour hot lava over me right now.

Comment: I also made an __assumption__ that calc, calc2 and calc3 are independent function calls which can called at the same time.